# Не понимаю почему выпадает в ошибку SEGMENTATION FAULT, подскажите пожалуйста

Tags: c

Должен по порядку отсортировать слова, но почему то выпадает в ошибку

```
        # include <stdio.h> 
          #include <unistd.h>               
         #include <stdlib.h>

    

    int     ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
    {
    int i=0;
    while (s1[i]) 
        {
            if (s1[i]>s2[i])
                return 1;
            if (s1[i]<s2[i])
                return -1;
            if (s1[i]==s2[i])
                return 0;
            i++;
        }
    return 66;
    
    
    }

    void ft_sort_string_tab(char **tab)
    {
    int i=0;
    char *tmp;
    
    while (tab[i]!=0)
    {
        if (ft_strcmp(tab[i], tab[i+1])==1)
        {
            tmp=tab[i];
            tab[i]=tab[i+1];
            tab[i+1]=tmp;
        }
        i++;
    }
    }

    int main(void) 
    {
    char *tab[3]={"ccc" "bbc" "abc"};

    int i=0;
    
    
    
    ft_sort_string_tab(tab);
    
    
    
    while (tab[i]!=0)
        {   
            
    printf("%s ", tab[i]);
    i++;
        }
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ft_strcmp(tab[i], tab[i+1])==1)
```

В этой строке выражение `tab[i+1]` - нулевой указатель. Функция `ft_strcmp` разыменовывает его. Программа падает.

Строки в инициализаторе массива не разделены запятыми. Компилятор склеивает их в одну строку. В вашем массиве будет одна строка и два нулевых указателя.

Когда вы исправите эти ошибки вы обнаружите что циклы обращаются за пределы массива и читают случайную память:

```
while (tab[i]!=0)
```

Алгоритм сортировки не сортирует.

Функция сравнения строк сравнивает только первые символы. Остальные не учитываются.

**P.S.** Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: "В этой строке выражение tab[i+1] - нулевой указатель. "- почему он нулевой а не 0+1 т.е. первый?

Comment: :) Нулевой, потому что он равен нулю. У него значение - `nullptr` или 0 в целочисленном выражении.

Comment: Так там же второе слово должно быть? в tab[1], не понимаю почему он нулевой. объясните идиоту плизз

Comment: Вот если так написать `char *tab[3]={"ccc", "bbc", "abc"};` то каждый указатель указывает на свою строчку. А у вас `tab[0]="cccbbcabc"`, `tab[1]=nullptr`, `tab[2]=nullptr`. @Stanislav Volodarskiy написал - вы не поставили запятые, компилятор склеил в одну строку.

Comment: "Вот если так написать char *tab[3]={"ccc", "bbc", "abc"};" - это то я понял, это я исправил давно, мне вот сейчас не понятно почему не сортирует?

Comment: У вас ошибка в алгоритме сортировки, потому не сортирует. Сравните ваш алгоритм с любым пузырьком. У вас один цикл, а надо два.

Comment: Циклы `while` промахиваются мимо массивов. Вы вовлекаете в сортировку мусор.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно написал @Stanislav Volodarskiy, у вас функция `ft_strcmp()` сравнивает только первые символы строк, а не полностью строки. При любом раскладе функция завершится после сравнения первого символа строк. А если бы не завершился после сравнения первого символа, то вышел бы за пределы массива.

```
       {
            if (s1[i]>s2[i])
                return 1;
            if (s1[i]<s2[i])
                return -1;
            if (s1[i]==s2[i])
                return 0;
            i++; // уже никогда не выполнится
        }
```

Все циклы в программе у вас выходят за пределы массивов.
В функции `ft_sort_string_tab()` массив `tab[]` состоит из 3 ненулевых элементов. А что произойдет, когда `i==3`? Попытка прочитать значение за пределами массива - неопределенное поведение (UB), чаще всего падение программы.

```
while (tab[i]!=0)
    {
       // ...
       i++;
    }
```

В `main()` - то же самое. `tab[]` из 3 ненулевых элементов, и вы пытаетесь прочитать значение `tab[3]`, а если программа не рухнет, попытаетесь прочитать значение `tab[4]` и т.д. пока программа рухнет. Так вот ошибка SEGMENTATION FAULT - выход за пределы массива или сегмента выделенной памяти, что вы везде успешно и делаете.

```
while (tab[i]!=0)
{   
    printf("%s ", tab[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за наглядное разъяснение. Если не сложно можете написать как следует организовать, чтобы он слова в алфавитном порядке расставил?

Comment: ВОт как задание выглядит:Create the function ft_sort_string_tab, by ascii order the strings in tab. • tab will be null terminated
• The sorting will be performed by exchanging the array’s pointers.
• Here’s how it should be prototyped :
 void ft_sort_string_tab(char **tab)

Comment: https://academy.yandex.ru/posts/osnovnye-vidy-sortirovok-i-primery-ikh-realizatsii?utm_source=telegram&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=academy_promo2022&utm_content=biblioteka_cc+_razrab    https://proglib.io/p/7-sposobov-sortirovki-massivov-na-primere-s-s-illyustraciyami-2022-04-20